# ASP.net connection with blob

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, blob, azure-blob-storage

How do I create a connection between asp.net web app hosted on azure and Blob?
The connection works perfectly when I upload files from my localhost to blob.
But when i publish the web app on azure, the app is unable to store file in the blob. The only reason I can think why the file does not get uploaded is because of some sort of connection issue between the hosted asp.net web app and the blob

**BlobStorageServices.cs**

```
     public class BlobStorageServices
{
    public CloudBlobContainer GetCloudBlobContainer()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("ImageStorageAccountConn"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myimages");
        if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            blobContainer.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });
        }
        return blobContainer;
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    BlobStorageServices _blobStorageService = new BlobStorageServices();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        if (image.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobStorageService.GetCloudBlobContainer();
            CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image.FileName);
            blob.UploadFromStream(image.InputStream);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <h2>Upload Image</h2>
    <p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
    </p>
```

Not sure if the BlobStorageServices.cs file gets uploaded to azure when we publish the asp.net app via visual studio.
ImageStorageAccountConn is the connecting string.

Comment: Is this running in a web/worker role instance? Or VM? Or Web App (app service)? You mentioned web app, but you have a call to `RoleEnvironment`

Comment: Thanks David. I removed RoleEnvironment and it works now.
I was struggling with this since last 2 days. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're actually using Web App (per your question): You are attempting to use the `RoleEnvironment` object to get the connection string. `RoleEnvironment` is specific to classic Cloud Services (web/worker role instances).